# How to Extract a Map object from another Map object Java

Tags: java, for-loop, dictionary, data-structures

I have the following data structure:

`Map<String,Map<String,String>>`

I'd like to extract its value (which itself is another string Map) from this complex Map object. I am currently doing it as such:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = getStructure(data,format);
Map<String,String> newMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

for(Entry<String, Map<String,String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    for (Entry<String, String> value : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
        newMap.put(value.getKey(),value.getValue());
    }
}
```

The above implementation gives me a new Map object with repeating key-value pairs due to the outer `foreach` loop, it is iterating through. Seems like I'm missing something.

How can I extract the inner Map object from the complex Map object?

**Edit:**

Addressing AlexWien's comment

Original Data Structure:

The reasoning behind the original data structure is to store a single value for a pair of IDs (ID1 and ID2). ID1 and ID2 may be different. So it is structured as:

`Map<String,Map<String,String>>` ===> `<someValue, <ID1,ID2>>`

What I am trying to achieve is to get the entire list of the id pairs (ID1 and ID2) for every someValue. So I can store them in a database to keep track of aeronautical information.

Comment: Are you wanting to extract a specific map with a given key?

Comment: Good question, I'd like to extract the entire Map (including all the keys)

Comment: @arabian_albert: There's not just one map.  There's many inner maps.  Which one of the inner maps do you want to extract?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I want all of them, so the entire list of Map

Comment: If you want all the inner maps as a collection, then that's just `map.values()`, which will give you a `Collection<Map<String, String>>`.

Comment: You should give an example what you want  to achieve. This is very confusing formulated.

Comment: If you need it to be a list, then you have no choice but to copy, but you can just do that as `List<Map<String, String>> mapList = new ArrayList<>(map.values());`

Comment: The question is do you simply need a Collection that exists in the outer Map?  If so use the List solution listed.  This will give you a list of Maps 

    Map<String,String>  

That will be your list of Maps with key value pairs.  If you are speaking of needing the keys that reference the map specifically I think your outer map is already supplying this.

Comment: Thanks guys. @AlexWien simple solution seemed to work for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an map of maps:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> map
```

you get the inner map simply by calling get

```
String key = ...;  // TODO
Map<String, String> innerMap = map.get(key);
```

**Update** to your edit:
It further seems you need something like a map of pairs:

```
Map<String, Pair<String, String>> mapOfPairs.
```

Unfortuneatly java has no Pair class.
So write one yourself:

```
public class Pair {
  String id1;
  String id2;
}
```

and have a

```
Map<String, Pair> mapOfPairs;
```